# Contacts.vcf file doesn't have all the information that is displayed by the Contacts app

Tags: android-contacts

I plugged my Android phone into my W11 so that I could backup some pictures and my contacts.  Easy enough.
I looked in the Contacts.vcf file just using 'vi' (which I assume is the file used by the Contacts app) and found that many of the vcards did not contain all of the information that is displayed by the Contacts app.  Why is that?  There must be more than one Contacts.vcf file or some other place from which the app gets the information.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the contacts application on my phone stores temporary data somewhere until it is actually exported to a file (even when power-cycled).  Once I exported it to a new .vcf file I could see all the data in that file.